# Change OS Status Bar Color in HTML-5 App

Tags: html, ios, css, statusbar

I am experimenting with HTML-5 apps with iOS *(I plan for this to work with Android and Windows Phone too)*

Here is a very basic template for the app

[image]

I want to change the white status bar to match the color of the apps toolbar, so it all looks more fluid

I want it to look like this

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">`

Comment: That half works - when I set it to black, the content on the status bar is black also, so you can't see anything in the status bar...any fixes for that?

Comment: Ignore my last comment - must have been a glitch with the phone - all sorted now!

Comment: with black or black-translucent? (to edit the answer for next people with same question)

Comment: With black there was a glitch, but it works. Black-translucent also works but the html ui needs to accommodate for the space taken up by the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this for Safari:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000" />
```

this works for me